# D3 v4 date ticks never display last item

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I'm using D3 v4 to build a very simple chart. I'm using a time scale for the x axis. I know that D3 maintains control over the number of ticks shown, when using a time scale. But that doesn't seem to explain the behavior here.

The codepen (linked below) shows an RTC of the behavior. I have 5 dates, defined very simply as `2018-10-10`, `2018-10-11`, and so on. I'm using `d3.scaleTime()` and `d3.axisBottom()`, nothing fancy.

No matter what I do, the last date is *never* included in the tick marks. Why is this happening?

[Here's a link to the codepen](https://codepen.io/danielvaughn/pen/oJgoNN?editors=0010)

Comment: for me the first date is not printed, reason TimeZone, do all your Date stuff in UTC, parsing, axes, .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain challenges while using timescale in d3. Here is the working code. You can update the tick format and height/width accordingly-

```
var svg = d3.select('#graph')
  .attr('width', '400px')
  .attr('height', '200px')

var data = [
  new Date('2018-10-10'),
  new Date('2018-10-11'),
  new Date('2018-10-12'),
  new Date('2018-10-13'),
  new Date('2018-10-14')
]

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([50, 350])

x.domain(d3.extent(data))

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x) .tickValues(data.map(function(d){return d}))
                .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")));
```

Comment: This is correct. It seems something to do specifically with the `tickValues()` call.